# jQuery reset star-rating.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this plugin https://danielupshaw.com/jquery-star-rating/

I want to reset my form. But how can I reset these stars??

```
 $("#btn-reset").on('click', function() {
  //some other inputs reset
  $('#starrating').star_rating.remove();
  $('#starrating').star_rating.reload();
 }
```

Please help on how to reset these stars to zero or null.

Here is the full code.

```
 $("#btn-reset").on('click', function() {
   $('#starrating').star_rating.reload();
});
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#starrating').star_rating({
        click: function(clicked_rating, event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('input[name=\'rating\']').val(clicked_rating);
            this.rating(clicked_rating);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The documentation is now updated at https://danielupshaw.com/jquery-star-rating/ , and also I left an answer that uses a method built-in to the plugin's API. Cool to see that you are using it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best approach, since I'm not familiar with this library...

But I achieved a reset like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.rating').star_rating();


  $("#resetStars").on("click",function(){
    $(".rating").remove();
    $('.star-rating').replaceWith("<span class='rating'>0/10 stars</span>");
    $(".rating").text("0/10").star_rating();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://danielupshaw.com/jquery-star-rating/jquery.star-rating.js"></script>


<h1>This is a good script!</h1>
<span class="rating">9.5/10 stars</span><br>
<br>
<br>
<button id="resetStars">Reset stars</button>
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. Thank you very much. Besides, it doesn't work if I use ID but works good if I use class. Not sure why. Thank you very much @Louys Patrice Bessette

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need to do is set the content to 0. Then re initialize the method.

```
$("#starrating").html("0");
$("#starrating").star_rating();
```

Comment: not working even after fixing ids. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/groovenectar/jquery-star-rating/master/jquery.star-rating.js check it once to see how can I call reload. I am not good in javascript

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the plugin, but looking at the link you provided, can't you just update the text inside of the element to reflect an empty or zero rating? Something like:

```
$("#btn-reset").on('click', function() {
     $('#starrating').text('0/5').star_rating();
}
```

Comment: not working. please help me how to call reload function?? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/groovenectar/jquery-star-rating/master/jquery.star-rating.js

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this; an attempt to **set default blank stars** on initial page load, or Click.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('i').addClass('fa-star-o');
});
```

Then refresh page to rest:

```
$( ".reset" ).click(function() {
    location.reload();
});
```

If you don't want to refresh page, you could try:

```
$( ".reset" ).click(function() {
   $('i').addClass('fa-star-o');
});
```

You may have to re-initiate your click feature on the star with similar jQuery to re add the appropriate Class when needed.

If this doesn't help or work; could you create a https://jsfiddle.net/ to fully replicate your issue; and then we could solve it. *If it were me; I'd find a better plugin to use or just write it from scratch at that point.*

Answer (score 0):

A bit another approach by re-rendering your rating stars from scratch using custom `renderRating` function.

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="rating-stars"></div>
<button class="reset-rating">Reset rating</button>
```

**JS:**

```js
var defaultRating = "0/5";

renderRating("3/5");

function renderRating(rating) {
  var ratingEl = $('<span />').addClass('rating');
  var ratingStr = rating || defaultRating;

  ratingEl.text(ratingStr);
  $('.rating-stars').html(ratingEl);
  ratingEl.star_rating();
}

$('.reset-rating').on('click', function() {
  renderRating();
})
```

[Preview on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0un1207g)

Answer (score 0):

This should reset it to 0:

`$('#starrating').star_rating('rating', 0);`

Here's the format to call the public methods:

`$('#starrating').star_rating('method_name');`

Should your click event be inside the document ready? If it is outside document ready, that can sometimes cause issue. I hope this helps :)